# instr() Query not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
$condition = '200,310'; //these are numbers of pages for news to be driven out of

while (list($key,$nesto) = each($pluginid))
{
 $getnm = $DB->query("SELECT articleid, categoryid FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "p".$nesto."_newy
                    WHERE lang = '$userlang'
                    AND settings > 0
                    **AND instr(categoryid, $condition)**
                    ORDER BY settings ASC, datecreated DESC");
$rows = $DB->get_num_rows($getnm);
}
```

This `instr` is not working.  Any ideas how to make this to work?  `categoryid` contains a single number.

Comment: The only way INSTR would return anything would be if categoryid was something like "200,310,450" - it would have to contain the condition. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Assuming a query succeeds is a bad way to go through life. Always check for success/failure before trying to do something with a result set - it might be a result set...

Comment: [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) is called with the full string, then the substring.  You have the parameters backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if categoryid is any of the ones provided in $condition, you have to switch the positions of the arguments:

```
AND instr('$condition', categoryid) > 0
```

Comment: Thx Darhazer that did the job :)))

Answer (score 2):

Try using `IN` instead of `INSTR`.  `IN` can use indexes, and may be faster than `INSTR`.

```
$DB->query("SELECT articleid, categoryid FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "p".$nesto."_newy
  WHERE lang = '$userlang'
  AND settings > 0
  AND categoryid IN ($condition)
  ORDER BY settings ASC, datecreated DESC");
```

Comment: Doesn't it need: `IN (".$condition.")` ?

Comment: @ypercube: No, as double quotes do variable interpolation.